# Cannot Import Sklearn Library for Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am pretty new to Python and am trying to `import train_test_split from sklearn.model_selection` for a machine learning project, using the code:

```
26:reviews = []
27:with open(file_name) as f:
28: for line in f:
29:     review = json.loads(line)
30:     reviews.append(Review(review['reviewText'], review['overall']))
31:from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
32:training,test = train_test_split(reviews, test_size = 0.4, random_state=45)
```

I am getting the error

```
"C:\Users\jacks\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
   from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
ImportError: cannot import name '__check_build' from partially initialized module 'sklearn' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I have tried googling around and have not found a reason for the error and I have downloaded the newest version of sklearn. I do not understand why the library is not importing correctly, nor why the error is for `"__check_build"` when I do not have anything in the code with that name. I am completely stuck. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install scipy, too:

```
pip install scipy
```

and restart the powershell

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am not sure how to restart the power shell. Do you mean restart my computer from the Powershell? If not then how might one restart the Powershell?

Comment: No i mean just close it and open it again if you start your programms from powershell/command-line. If you use an idle, just restart the idle.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed scikit-learn with the following in the terminal:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

If it doesn't work I would recommend trying the following, going through anaconda:

```
conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn
```